# Mysterious Intersection on Association

Tags: bugs, associations, intersection

**This bug has been fixed in version 13.0**

---

I have try to do an intersection on list of associations and the result is astonishing. Here an example:

```
Intersection[{<|a -> 0|> , <|b -> 1|>},  {<|a -> 0, b -> 1|> }]
```

Normally I do expect that the intersection is empty since no elements coincide between the two lists. However the result is

```
{<|a -> 0, b -> 1|>}
```

My question is : **Why this result ?**

It is however  possible to get the expected result by setting SameTest -> SameQ

Comment: Looks like a bug. I have reported it internally.

Comment: in 11.3 , it throws `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {<|a->0|>,<|b->1|>} {<|a->0,b->1|>} cannot be combined.` `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {<|a->0,b->1|>} {<|a->0|>,<|b->1|>} cannot be combined.` and returns `{<|a -> 0, b -> 1|>} {<|a -> 0|>, <|b -> 1|>}`

Comment: @wuyudi It was missing a comma in the example code, I have just corrected that.

Comment: Perhaps the intersection is being done on the values?

Comment: Interestingly, `Intersection[{<|a -> 0|>, <|...|>},  {<|a -> 0, b -> 1|>}]` produces the same (buggy) result for any sequence of rules `...`, namely `<|a -> 0, b -> 1|>`.

Answer (score 6):

fyi, Fixed in V 13.0

[image]

---

Compare to

[image]